# KeyError using dictionary in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

I am trying to write a program to find pair of numbers for a particular sum. It uses a dictionary to store the numbers and find the pair accordingly. The code is as follows:

```
def printpairs(A, arr_size, sum):
    hash = {}
    for i in A:
        hash[i] = None
    for i in range(0,arr_size):
        temp = sum - A[i]
        if (temp >= 0 and hash[temp] == 1):
            print sum, A[i], temp
        hash[A[i]] = 1


A = [1,4,45,6,10,8]
printpairs(A, 6, 16)
```

I am getting error :

```
Keyerror : 15
```

I am not getting where I am going wrong.

Comment: Please always post full tracebacks

Comment: You don't need to pass in `arr_size`; you can do `arr_size = len(A)` if you need it. But you don't need it; you can iterate directly over `A`. Also, it's good practice to not use `sum` and other names of built-ins as variable names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few notes that will help you understanding your problem:

- `hash` has the same size as `A`, in your example, it's 6 and its keys are the items in `A`
- In the first iteration, `temp` is `16 - A[0]` -> `16 - 1` -> 15
- `hash[temp]` doesn't exist since `A` doesn't contain 15

Please note that you don't need to pass the list's size, you can have it within the function by using `len`. Also when having this kind of problems, consider using the debugger, it'll help you find your problem faster than people on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please can you suggest a debugger? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Python raises a `KeyError` whenever a `dict()` object is requested
>   (using the format `a = adict[key]`) and the key is not in the
>   dictionary.
>
> If you don't want to have an exception but would rather a default
>   value used instead, you can use the `get()` method:

```
A.get(15, 'default_value')
```